# How to make this CSS correctly on iPhone?

Tags: css, iphone, svg, safari

I'm losing my mind over this. The iPhone is screwing up the CSS in the mobile menu on this website:
http://www.kinderlogopediemaassluis.nl

The problem is with the green SVG background under the hamburger icon.
In all the emulators that I am testing, it shows up correctly:
http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.kinderlogopediemaassluis.nl

But for some reason on an actual physical iPhone, this happens:
[image: iPhone problem]

Can anyone find the problem?

Comment: This is expected duo to shrinking the width, what do you expect?

Comment: I'm expecting the green SVG to align to the left side of the screen

Comment: I see there are two inline <img>'s thats why they are beside each other. You can make both of them position absolute and play with z-index to put icon on top

Comment: @AbdullahAlemadi Thanks for the suggestion. I did make them both absolute and now it is working... sort of.

Comment: Good luck man. :)